# How to serialize/deserialize data to file in Rascal MPL

Tags: caching, serialization, metaprogramming, rascal

I need a way to serialize data in Rascal as some operations may be relatively slow and some quick form of caching is desired. For example the construction of ASTs.

I'm using the following segment of code to construct ASTs from the project at the indicated location:

```
list[Declaration] getASTs(loc projectLocation) {
    M3 model = createM3FromMavenProject(projectLocation);
    list[Declaration] asts = [createAstFromFile(f, true)
        | f <- files(model.containment), isCompilationUnit(f)];
    return asts;
}
```

Now constructing a particular AST takes some time (around 2-3 seconds). I therefore wish to cache the result inside some dump file:

```
loc smallsqlLoc = projectLoc + "smallsql0.21_src";
loc dumpLoc = projectLoc + "dump/smallsql.bin";

if(!exists(dumpLoc)) {
    list[Declaration] dumpAsts = getASTs(smallsqlLoc);
    writeFile(dumpLoc, dumpAsts);
}
```

And read it back into memory (which hopefully will be way faster):

```
if(!exists(dumpLoc))
    throw "Error: dump does not exist.";
list[Declaration] asts = readFile(dumpLoc);
```

But the return type of readFile is `str`, not `list[Declaration]`. A simple cast will obviously not solve the problem. How can I get the AST I originally wrote to the file back into memory? More generally, how to serialize and deserialize any data type from/to a file in Rascal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`writeBinaryValueFile`](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/library/valueio/#ValueIO-writeBinaryValueFile) (and the `readBinaryValueFile`) they takes care of reading and writing almost any rascal value (the exception is functions, we cannot serialize them).

The `writeFile` you are using is for text files, but those are not meant for data storage (unless you are generating source code offcourse).

usage example:

```
model = createM3FromMavenProject(projectLocation);
writeBinaryValueFile(|tmp:///test.cache|, model);
model2 = readBinaryValueFile(#M3, |tmp:///test.cache|);
```

So, regarding caching, if you want cross-runtime caching, `writeBinaryValueFile` is the way to go. If you need caching inside the same session, you can take a look at the `@memo` tag, that behaves as a cache.  It's not documented that clearly, but you can take a peek at the tests around this feature: [lang::rascal::tests::basic::Memoization](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/blob/main/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/rascal/tests/basic/Memoization.rsc).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Sadly I don't yet have enough rep to upvote your answer. For future readers: the type to be read can be indicated by using `#`: `readBinaryValueFile(#list[Declaration], ...)`.

Comment: thanks @teuncm I've added an example to the answer, that was missing indeed.